# How to include assets from an external gem in my custom gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to refactor out some of the common code used across several internal sites into a gem that could be used as a baseline configuration for existing and future sites.  So for example all of these sites include the backbone-on-rails gem.  I've created a custom gem, included backbone-on-rails in the Gemfile for this new gem and ran bundle install.  I then removed the reference to backbone-on-rails from an existing project and added the new gem to that Gemfile. Ran bundle install there to pick it up expecting the existing app to get backbone via the custom gem.  However this didn't work.  I realize I could just download backbone and add it to assets in the new Gem, but I would really like to use this new gem to include 3rd party gems like backbone-on-rails in multiple projects.  Any pointers on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should work, are you requiring your custom gem assets from the main application assets?

Comment: Thanks for the response Pierre.  Not sure I understand.  Basically I have the backbone gem in the gemfile for my custom gem.  Then I have the custom gem included in a rails app. Do I need to add a require somepleace to have the assets from the backbone gem be added to the rails app via the custom gem?

Comment: Pardon if I miss your point, but there is a configuration option in config/environments/xxx.rb (for instance, production.rb) where you can define external asset stores.